# I want to Select data from mysql DB which are older than 1 month

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to select data from my mysql database which are older than 1 month. I tried this query. It does not work. What is the correct query?

```
SELECT * FROM `mails` WHERE `received_time` BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

Comment: This query would work if you reversed the two values in BETWEEN. The lower bound (the earlier date value) has to be first. The upper bound (the later date value) has to be last.  Swap those around and you'll be good. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT * FROM `mails` WHERE `received_time` < DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

Your received_time column must be in datetime format like '2015-05-17 23:30:40'.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that when using a `BETWEEN` comparison, the lower bound must be specified first, and the upper bound last.

As a demonstration, try this query:

```
SELECT 2 BETWEEN 1 AND 3
     , 2 BETWEEN 3 AND 1
```

The first expression evaluates to TRUE (returns a 1), the second expression evaluates to FALSE (returns a 0).

Just reorder the two values in the `BETWEEN` and you'll be good.

---

This will return rows that are "within" the past month:

```
  WHERE received_time BETWEEN NOW() + INTERVAL -1 MONTH AND NOW()
```

That's equivalent to

```
  WHERE received_time >= NOW() + INTERVAL -1 MONTH
    AND received_time <= NOW()
```

If you only want rows that are "earlier" than a particular date, then don't use a `BETWEEN` comparison, just use an inequality comparison. To return all rows that were received over one month ago e.g.

```
  WHERE received_date < NOW() + INTERVAL -1 MONTH
```